# minimum/maximum depth of tile in opengl

Tags: opengl, opengl-4, compute-shader, deferred-rendering

I'm trying to implement tiled deferred rendering but I'm stuck on calculating min/max depth for each tile. I'm using compute shader for this. This is its complete code:

```
#version 430

#define TILE_SIZE 32

layout (location = 0, rgba32f) uniform image2D u_texture;
layout (location = 1, rgba32f) uniform image2D depthtex; 

layout (local_size_x = TILE_SIZE, local_size_y = TILE_SIZE) in;

shared uint min_depth;
shared uint max_depth;

void main(void){
    ivec2 pos = ivec2(gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy);
    ivec2 grid = ivec2(gl_WorkGroupID.xy);

    if(gl_LocalInvocationIndex == 0){
        min_depth = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        max_depth = 0;
    }

    vec4 color;
    vec4 color_tex = imageLoad(depthtex,pos);
    float d = color_tex.x;

    uint depth = uint(d * 0xFFFFFFFF);

    atomicMin(min_depth, depth);
    atomicMax(max_depth, depth);

    barrier();

    color = vec4(float(float(min_depth) / float(0xFFFFFFFF)));

    imageStore(u_texture, grid, color);
}
```

When I try to run program it cycles in infinite loop in compute shader compilation. Any idea why is this caused and how to fix it?

EDIT: so I found out that problem is caused by *glGetProgramiv()* function when I try to check linking status of compute shader which I'm doing with this code:

```
//throw exception if linking failed
    GLint status;
    glGetProgramiv(_object, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == GL_FALSE) {
        std::string msg("Program linking failure: ");

        GLint infoLogLength;
        glGetProgramiv(_object, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLogLength);
        char* strInfoLog = new char[infoLogLength + 1];
        glGetProgramInfoLog(_object, infoLogLength, NULL, strInfoLog);
        msg += strInfoLog;
        delete[] strInfoLog;

        glDeleteProgram(_object); _object = 0;
        throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }
```

However, if I remove *atomicMin()* from my shader everything works fine.

Comment: yes I understand but I did not find solution to my problem... My problem was that atmoic function causes compute shader linking check to run in infinite loop and I found why but not how to fix it